# Speech recognition program is randomly displaying pre-defined word(defined in 'GramarBuilder()') for those spoken words that doesn't exist in Grammar

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, speech-recognition

I'm a novice to C# i'm not sure if I'm writing on the right forum. I am building simple speech recognition program which takes voice command as input, performs speech to text translation and then searches a video matching to that text.

> I am using `grammarBuider()` and define my own grammar for more
>   accurate speech recognition. But the problem is: when any word that
>   doesn't exit in grammar is spoken, the program starts
>   any displaying/writing existing word randomly which were defined in
>   grammar.

So,

> What I want is: If any word that doesn't exist in my grammar `Grammarbuilder` is spoken, the program should not write any or any random word from grammar on screen. Instead, it should display a message to user i.e. "word you spoke doesn't exist in program's grammar OR no video found matching to your voice search"

Could anyone advise me How can I fix this problem?
Here is my code..

```
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnStart.Enabled = false;
            btnStop.Enabled = true;
            clist.Add(new string[] { "go away", "able", "active", "actual", "afraid", "busy", "casual" });
            Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(clist));
            try
            {
                sre.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
                sre.LoadGrammar(gr);
                sre.SpeechRecognized+= sre_SpeechRecognized;
                sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");

            }

    }
        void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBoxContent.Text += e.Result.Text.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;     


        }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            sre.RecognizeAsyncStop();
            btnStart.Enabled = true;
            btnStop.Enabled = false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe in detail what happens when word that doesn't exit in grammar is spoken?

Comment: program start displaying any pre-defined word. My grammar currently have these words { "go away", "able", "active", "actual", "afraid", "busy", "casual" }) but I any other word lets say 'hello' is spoken, it starts displaying afraid or able  etc.

Answer (score 3):

Each recognition result has a [confidence score](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.recognizedphrase.confidence(v=vs.110).aspx) - a relative measure of the certainty of correct recognition of a phrase. It looks like your `SpeechRecognitionEngine` raises `SpeechRecognized` event whether the confidence is high or low, providing the best match. Try to check these scores when recognizing words not included in the grammar. If I am right and this is the problem, then you have following options:

- Check e.Result.Confidence at the `sre_SpeechRecognized` and display a message to user  if the score is too low
- Try to set a confidence threshold for `SpeechRecognitionEngine` and handle `SpeechRecognitionRejected` event. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.recognizedphrase.confidence(v=vs.110).aspx) claims that

> If your application is using a SpeechRecognitionEngine instance, you can modify the confidence level at which speech input is accepted or rejected with one of the UpdateRecognizerSetting methods.

Try calling `SpeechRecognitionEngine.UpdateRecognizerSetting` to set it. I don't know how exactly is this setting called, but [this outdated documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/speech-technologies/dd167797(v=office.14)) states that it is `'CFGConfidenceRejectionThreshold'`.

Good luck!

Comment: This is a good advice. Can be coded to something like: `if (e.Result.Confidence >= 0.75) textBoxContent.AppendText(e.Result.Text); else if (e.Result.Confidence > 0.60 & e.Result.Confidence < 0.75)  textBoxContent.AppendText("Not sure, repeat"); else textBoxContent.AppendText("I can't hear you");`. Also, the [`AudioStateChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.audiostatechanged(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) event should be subscribed, to give a warning if the audio level is too low.